# PyQT5 QMovie gives some unknown error on init

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt5

I have this widget:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class LoadingCircle(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoadingCircle, self).__init__(parent)
        self.movie = QtGui.QMovie('/home/rk/Files/project/run/data/misc/gui/loading.gif')
        self.hide()
        self.setMovie(self.movie)
        print(self.movie.lastErrorString())
        
        
    def start(self):
        self.movie.start()
        self.show()
        
    def stop(self):
        self.movie.stop()
        self.hide()
```

When I add it to my app I see this in console: "Unknown error".
And I can't see my gif after "start" method executed.
I checked plugins and I have 'libqgif.so' in plugins folder.
How to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have *only* that message? Are you *completely* sure about the path? Is the gif valid? Have you tried another gif? When does the error appear? Also, how is the instance created and the `start()` called?

Comment: @musicamante I tried only that gif and I'm sure in the path. I  tried to look at self.movie.isValid() and it's true. And self.movie.format() is correct.
I added QWidget in Qt Designer and changed it to my widget with "transform to" menu in Qt Designer. I did it with another widget and it works good, but it doesn't have gif animation.

Comment: Please be more specific by [edit]ing your question and add both more details and a proper [mre].

Comment: Calling `lastErrorString()` will always output "Unknown error", whether there's an actual error or not. The code works fine for me with a valid gif.